# Github showing (develop) branch behind master by x commits

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have been searching for the answer to this problem but have not found a solution or explanation.

We just switched to Github for our repo and are still trying to find the best way to use it in a team environment. Our current workflow is like this:

We have two branches `develop` and `master`

1. Developer clones `develop` branch onto their machine and creates a branch using: `git clone https://github.com/username/repo`
2. Developer creates the branch for the feature they are working on using: `git checkout -b branchname`
3. Developer finishes branch and pushes to Github using: `git pull` then `git push -u origin branchname`
4. Developer creates pull request and the lead developer will first merge the just pushed branch into `develop` and then merges `develop` into `master`

Now the thing that concerns me and makes me wonder if we are doing something wrong is that when we look at the `master` branch in Github everything appears fine, but when we view the `develop` branch inside of Github it says `This branch is x commits behind master`. Everytime we merge a pull request the number `x` goes up. Github gives the option on the same line to "Compare" or create a "Pull Request" but when I click either of those options it shows the branches are identical.

I have tried to fixed this previously by merging `master` into `develop` which does make the branches both even but as soon as a pull request is merged we get the same problem again.

When we first switched to Github I don't ever recall seeing that `develop` was behind `master` but our workflow has not changed. I don't know if maybe I just didn't notice it before or not.

If I compare the commits between the branches I can see that in fact `develop` is behind `master` by `x` number of commits. The commits that are showing up are the ones where I merge `develop` into `master`. What I am wondering is if it is something to be concerned about? The branches are identical besides the number of commits. Are we not using Git/Github correctly and is that why we are getting this, or is this a normal thing?

Comment: You may want to read through the [list of workflows over at Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow/).  Our preference is the 'forking' workflow when doing GitHub.

Comment: I'm bothered by the exact same thing, and it even affects forking workflows (the child forks will be "behind" by the number of merge commits). I'm left to believe that this is just a benign quirk of github; a weird print statement, rather than an actual indication of a problem.

Comment: Probably a result of commit squashing (or re-base) when merging with a development branch, and not checking out to your default branch before starting to work on a new feature. This leads you default branch to have 1 commit (squashed) and the feature branch you are working on has the unsquashed version

Answer (score 5):

Your `master` branch is your base branch. You should only merge `develop` into `master` when you're absolutely sure everything works.

`This branch is x commits behind master` is just an information message that you don't need to worry about. Your only worry is making sure that `master` is as it should be.

Once you're done with the project and merge everything into `master`, you can delete any branches you created in the process.